# Deploy Spring MVC Web App in Tomcat-8 Error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I try to deploy my Spring MVC Web app to tomcat-8, and I have the errors like below. I create a Maven project for my Spring MVC web app using Eclipse. I was thinking it is Tomcat issue and try to follow the suggestion.

> Stop the tomcat server.
>       Remove all your project first from Tomcat webapp and wptwebapp directories by manually.
>       Remove Catalina folder which is inside the work directory.
>       Start tomcat with no project deployed.
>       If it is started clearly deploy your app and run again.

But it gives me the following errors:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\webapps\springMvc-1.0.0.war
Oct 06, 2015 5:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springMvc-1.0.0]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:461)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1493)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1432)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:210)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@4209cbd]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5004)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 45 more
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@5e1996fa]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:689)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 51 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:89)
... 52 more
Oct 06, 2015 5:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\webapps\springMvc-1.0.0.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springMvc-1.0.0]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:461)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1493)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1432)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:210)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)Oct 06, 2015 5:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\webapps\springMvc-1.0.0.war has finished in 17,006 ms
Oct 06, 2015 5:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

How can I fix the above errors? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your WAR file is bad. Relevant bit of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:89)
```